# Bash script to read ids from file and spawn process in a controlled manner

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to read hundreds of ids from a file and pass those to another shell script as parameters to be spawned as separate child requests. [Done]

But we cannot spawn more than 6 child requests i.e., not more than 6 requests can be running at a given point in time.

I have gone through this site (references given below) and others and came to know that you can get the PID of the spawned process using $! but am faraway from implementing it as I do not know how to store them in an array and delete it once the spawned process is complete.

[Forking / Multi-Threaded Processes | Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455695/forking-multi-threaded-processes-bash)

[How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/usr/share/nginx/html/cron/userids.txt" //file containing the userids that needs to be spawned

MAXCOUNT=6 //maximum number of child request that can be spawned

while IFS= read -r line
do
    #submit a background job here

    sh fetch.sh $line & //this is the shell script that needs to be submitted

    //check if the spawned request count is less than MAXCOUNT
    //If it is then wait for one or more request to finish 
    //If the number of child requests is less than MAXCOUNT then spawn another request 
    //if all the lines are read then wait till all the child process completes and then exit

done <"$file"
```

Please be cognizant that I am newbie and do not know much about the shell process.

Will appreciate any directions and feedback.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **GNU Parallel** for this:

```
parallel -j6 -a "$file" fetch.sh
```

It has lots of options for handling failures, progress bars, logging etc.

Comment: Went through this and it seems like it will solve the issue I am facing. After installing it when I run it it shows an error as "Permission denied" for the file I am trying to execute. I am on Ubuntu and I am able to run the said package from command line also, but with **parallel** it is throwing error. Any suggestions? Do I need to configure anything else for **parallel** before running it.

Comment: I am guessing you haven’t put a shebang at the first line of your script. Or you haven’t made your script executable with `chmod +x script.sh`. Either do those two things or use `sh script.sh` in place of `script.sh`.

Comment: Found the issue. Move the code to another place and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs` to spawn a maximum number of processes passing the arguments read from stdin

```
xargs -n 1 -P 6 fetch.sh < "$file"
```